# The amchart5 graph library suddenly doesn't work in Eclipse, jquery

Tags: jquery, amcharts5

The amchart5 graph library works on my personal project

I'm trying to use the code in the company project, and the error appears as below.. I've been trying, but it's not working.. I think it's a problem with other libraries, but I don't know exactly.. It's awkward

https://www.amcharts.com/demos/word-cloud/

```
 <!-- amchart check -->
   <script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/index.js"></script>
   <script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/wc.js"></script>
   <script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/themes/Animated.js"></script>
<!-- 그래프 위치 -->
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
<!-- 클릭 트리거-->
<div class = "amchart_check_JS upload_commute_control_button" >제발 나와라 얍</div>
<style>
#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
</style>


<scripts>
$(document).on('click','.amchart_check_JS',function(){
   var root = am5.Root.new("chartdiv");

   
   // Set themes
   // https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/concepts/themes/
   root.setThemes([
     am5themes_Animated.new(root)
   ]);
   
   
   // Add series
   // https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/charts/word-cloud/
   var series = root.container.children.push(am5wc.WordCloud.new(root, {
     maxCount:100,
     minWordLength:2,
     maxFontSize:am5.percent(35),
     text: "Though yet of Hamlet our dear brother's death The memory be green, and that it us befitted To bear our hearts in grief and our whole kingdom To be contracted in one brow of woe, Yet so far hath discretion fought with nature That we withback to school in Wittenberg, It is most retrograde to our desire: And we beseech you, bend you to remain Here, in the cheer and comfort of our eye, Our chiefest courtier, cousin, and our son.",
   }));
   
   
   // Configure labels
   series.labels.template.setAll({
     paddingTop: 5,
     paddingBottom: 5,
     paddingLeft: 5,
     paddingRight: 5,
     fontFamily: "Courier New"
   });
   
})
</scripts>
```